# Running Function Inside Stub. Passing Function Pointer

Tags: c++, c, function, pointers, function-parameter

I'm working on creating a user-level thread library and what I want to do is run a function inside a stub and so I would like to pass the function pointer to the stub function.

Here is my stub function:

```
void _ut_function_stub(void (*f)(void), int id)
{
    (*f)();
    DeleteThread(id);
}
```

This is what the user calls. What I want to do is get pointer of _ut_function_stub to assign to **pc** and I've tried various different options including casting but the compiler keeps saying "*invalid use of void expression*".

```
int CreateThread (void (*f) (void), int weight)
{
    ... more code

    pc = (address_t)(_ut_function_stub(f, tcb->id));

    ... more code
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Either way, the problem is that you want the address of `_ut_function_stub`, but you're trying to cast the result of a function **call**...

Comment: C. I added the C++ tag figuring it would be the same concept.

Comment: I tried using the & to grab the address. The compiler says "*lvalue required as unary & operand*"

Comment: This might actually be a lot easier in C++ since you could use a [functor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object#In_C_and_C.2B.2B) to save a function and its arguments, which looks like what you're trying to do.

Comment: @ThePedestrian: But there is no address.  You're trying to operate on a function *call* in your above code.  If the problem is that you somehow want to save the combination of the function pointer **and** some arguments to call it with, then that's not natively supported in C.  You would need to construct a [*functor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_object).

Comment: Is there a way to capture the program counter of the function call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in implementing your own user-level-threads library, I'd suggest looking into the (now deprecated) [`ucontext`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/ucontext.h.html) implementation. Specifically, looking at the definitions for the structs used in [`ucontext.h`](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/system/i386_deb50/os/usr/include/sys/ucontext.h) will help you see all the stuff you actually need to capture to get a valid snapshot of the thread state.

What you're really trying to capture with the erroneous `(address_t)` cast in your example is the current [continuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation). Unfortunately, C doesn't support first-class continuations, so you're going to be stuck doing something much more low-level, like swapping stacks and dumping registers (hence why I pointed you to `ucontext` as a reference—it's going to be kind of complicated if you really want to get this right).

Comment: I should also point out that any solution, in addition to being complicated, is also going to be non-portable. You have to do something very different to [make ucontext work on windows](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4225/Unix-ucontext_t-Operations-on-Windows-Platforms) vs a unix-like system.